# Acknowledgment on Publish with Spring AMQP

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Is there any way a publisher can be acknowledged that a published message has been delivered to a listener when using Spring AQMP? I have a number of queues where I set `x-message-ttl = 0`, which means messages will be discarded if they cannot be immediately delivered, but as I'm using this in a request/reply scenario, I'd like to be able to abort the request and handle an error immediately.

Answer (score 2):

You could publish a message with the [`mandatory` flag](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.publish).

> If this flag is set, the server will return an undeliverable message
>   with a Return method. If this flag is zero, the server will queue the
>   message, but with no guarantee that it will ever be consumed.

And set [a return callback](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/amqp.html#template-confirms) which will be called if the message in unroutable.

Another solution should be to use an [alternate exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html) associated to your exchange. The cons are that you need to bind a queue to this AE and consume messages to be able to know if a request has failed.